# Manually writing Json into SQL column using SQL Functions

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Hello I need to write a JSON into a SQL column
during a insert in a stored procedure.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (ColumnA)
SELECT
  '{"PropertyA":' + '"' + valueA + '"' + ',"PropertyB":' + '"' + valueB + '"}
FROM TableB
```

The above works, and it inserts the following: {"PropertyA:""SomeValue","PropertyB:""AnotherValue"}

But I'm hoping to format the statement into something more legible using SQL Functions if they exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for `FROM OPENJSON(<jsonstring>)`

See this example from the documentation

```sql
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = N'[
  {"id": 2, "info": {"name": "John", "surname": "Smith"}, "age": 25},
  {"id": 5, "info": {"name": "Jane", "surname": "Smith"}, "dob": "2005-11-04T12:00:00"}
]';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
  WITH (
    id INT 'strict $.id',
    firstName NVARCHAR(50) '$.info.name',
    lastName NVARCHAR(50) '$.info.surname',
    age INT,
    dateOfBirth DATETIME2 '$.dob'
  );
```

Comment: Slayton, thanks for contributing. If you could edit your answer to include an actual explicit solution or reproducible example that would be great, and in line with community requirements. Link is good, but as a support to your solution.